# Connect to Azure Point to Site VPN via Script

Tags: azure, automation, windows-10, vpn, azure-vpn

I have a working Azure Point-to-Site VPN on Windows 10.

See this guide for instructions: https://www.starwindsoftware.com/blog/configuring-azure-point-to-site-vpn-with-windows-10

I'd like my computer to make the VPN connection on login. I know how to make Task Scheduler run a script on login. How can I make a script that will perform these two manual steps shown in the image below (mentioned in the article)?
[image: VPN Connect Dialogs]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have a try on these commands working for me.

```
rasphone  "vNet_GET-CMD"
$wshell = New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell;
$wshell.AppActivate('Network Connections')
Sleep 2
$wshell.SendKeys('~')
Sleep 2
$wshell.SendKeys('~')
```

[image]

Comment: You're amazing! The first time you launch, there is a separate prompt that says `Connection Manager needs elevated privilege to run the following Custom Action(s) to proceed with the connection. CMROUTE.DLL - to update your routing table`. Select the `Do not show this message again for this Connection` checkbox and click `Continue`.