# WORKS from VPN SETTINGS but NOT RASPHONE - Custom script (to update your routing table) failed (8007026f)

Tags: azure, shell, vpn

In win 10 settings window I can click and connect.

```
rasphone -d "MyConnectionName"
```

however ends up with:

Custom script (to update your routing table) failed (8007026f).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem might occur if you are trying to open the point-to-site VPN connection by using a shortcut.

Solution: directly [connect from a Windows VPN client](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-howto-point-to-site-resource-manager-portal#to-connect-from-a-windows-vpn-client) via UI.

If you want to connect it automatically, try the following PowerShell Commands from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59753349/connect-to-azure-point-to-site-vpn-via-script).

```
rasphone  "vNet_GET-CMD"
$wshell = New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell;
$wshell.AppActivate('Network Connections')
Sleep 2
$wshell.SendKeys('~')
Sleep 2
$wshell.SendKeys('~')
```